# $L^p$-norm of a.e. limit

Tags: integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n(x) \in L^p (X)$ be a sequence of functions that converge a.e. to some function $f(x)$. Assume that $|f_n|_p \le M$ for all $n$. Also, assume that it turned out that $f(x) \in L^p (X)$. Does it follow that $|f|_{p} \le M$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it is true that $\|f\|_p \le M$. In fact, you don't even need the assumption that $f \in L^p$, since it follows from the fact that $f_n \to f$ a.e and $\|f_n\|_p \le M$ for any $n \in \mathbb N_+$.

Comment: @DominikKutek I can't see why it holds. Could you please elaborate on it or could you give a reference?

Comment: Use Fatou's lemma.